# Adobe Edge issue - animation shows what looks like skid marks

Tags: javascript, adobe-edge

New to using Adobe Edge, though very familiar with Flash/AS. I need to do animation sequence that is not flash-based, so trying out Adobe Edge. The animation itself is all done, everything works correctly. However, when the JS is loaded on the site and viewed (at least in Chrome/FF) when an object is easing out it creates black bars behind it - looks like it's skidding to a halt.

These disappear when anything is moved - background, any div, anything layered on top, etc. Can handle with setInterval flashing a transparent div on top of it, but seems a bit of a ridiculous way to solve. Has anybody else run into this? Is there a setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out after ton of testing, etc. Basically the way Adobe Edge works - at least at this point - is that if you put the animation on top of something else, the background color will "leak" through the animation and show up as skid mark looking lines. After playing with every setting in their UI, nothing would handle. Final work around was to put a background image behind the animation that matched, so when it showed through it wasn't detectable.